# How can I use the rewrite engine to access my api outside of public_html

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a webspace directory structure similar to the following

- `website`

  - `api`
  - `public_html`

    - `assets`

The problem is that I need to access the files in the api folder from an AJAX call within a JavaScript file within `public_html`. I was thinking I could use Apache rewrite rules to accomplish this. The AJAX call would use the following url, for example, `"api/example.php"` and with the use of the rewrite engine, hopefully, that would get rewritten to access the file in the api folder outside the website root.

I don't have much experience with the Apache rewrite engine at all, so I wouldn't have even the slightest of ideas, if possible, on how to accomplish this.

Would appreciate any help at all, thanks.

Comment: I would use [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) instead. There's no need to complicate this with URL rewriting. Give `Alias` a try and come back here if you have any issues

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rewriting the urls, you should configure apache to also service the API directory. This can be done via an alias. Here is an example:

```
Alias /api/ "/var/www/website/api"
<Directory "/var/www/website/api/">
</Directory>
```

Comment: i think it is same as subdomain but with apache config. Am I right, gempir?

Comment: Yes this would be the same subdomain. This would servce your api files under your.domain.com/api

Comment: Please note, `Alias` is not valid inside `.htaccess` so OP will need access to modify the server / virtual-host config

Comment: @Phil I'm unfamilar with shared hosting. Is this something unsual? Is having access to the virtual-host config not given every time?

Comment: @gempir depends on the host. If it's using something like CPanel or Plesk, I'm sure it's possible

Comment: @Phil Yea, so I'm using 1and1 as the hosting provider, and [I'm pretty sure](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/htaccess-c37776/modify-the-apache-configuration-a596185.html) I don't have access to edit the Apache config, only `.htaccess` files. Therefore, according to that article, I'm pretty sure I won't be able to even use `mod_alias`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve it with the help of subdomain, create subdomain from cpanel and set api as root directory then you can access api folder in ypur ajax call with the help of subdomain. Hope this will help for you.

Comment: Please note that using a sub-domain introduces [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) related issue which OP would need to take care of. I'm not saying it's a bad idea, just something to be aware of

Comment: What I worry about if I use this technique is that the `PHP` files in the api folder can be publicly accessed. For example, any user could go to api.domainname.com/example.php and access the `PHP` files. The reason I originally wanted to use Apache's rewrite engine to access the api outside of the website root is that it would leave the api files harder to access than just typing in their name in the URL search bar.

Comment: @Jacob you can provide security to that api file with the help of hash key or any base 64 pattern user and pass key, so if someone try to access that api url e.g. subdomain.xyz.com/api.php then he must to pass access hash key & password.

Comment: @SurajWasnik Eh this might work, I don't know. I was sort of just hoping for people to provide me with some rewrite rules instead of providing me with different solutions to the problem like using a subdomain or `mod_alias`.